# CQ5 prevent deleting of a page

Tags: aem

I'm guessing if there's a way to catch the event fired after the delete of a page before the resource is no longer available.

My problem is that if I click the delete button, for a page on the  local `4502/siteadmin` console, I get the delete event but, during the catch, the resource is no more available so I can't no longer get its properties.

Any advice for a solution?

Comment: So, what exactly are you trying to do in the catch block?

Answer (score 3):

Unless it's a kind of processing when you want to decide whether given user should or shouldn't be able to remove the page I recommend you using the ACLs for defining such constraints.
Refer to official docs: [Users and groups](https://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/administering/user_group_ac_admin.html), [ACLs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-2/developing/access_rights.html), [Useradmin in CQ](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/administering/security.html)

On the other way, if you need the processing you might want to prevent the action by including a request [request filter](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html) or overriding a [`WcmCommand`](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/commands/WCMCommand.html). For more details take a look at your developer console in the browser and investigate the request that is send on Delete button click.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to avoid the deletion of a page is to set up ACL's. You can use groups and configure permissions for these groups. Once a group has no delete permission on a page, none of the members will be able to delete pages.